# calculate total pause duration in ios/cocos2d

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

While playing any iphone puzzle game, user can press pause button multiple times. So I want to calculate the total pause duration of that perticular puzzle level. I want to use NSTimer to start it when pause button is pressed and stop it when resume button is pressed. Is this the best way or any other suggetion? Can anyone help quick syntax for start/stop. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Start by declaring global variables to store pause dates:

```
NSDate *pauseStart;
NSTimeInterval pauseDuration;
```

then in your methods that start and stop pause, you record date for start and date for end. Then calculate difference between two dates.

```
-(void)pauseStart 
{
    pauseStart = [NSDate date];
}

-(void)pauseEnd 
{
   NSDate *pauseEnd = [NSDate date];
   pauseDuration = pauseDuration + [pauseEnd timeIntervalSinceDate:pauseStart];

   NSLog(@"Total duration of pause is: %.f seconds", pauseDuration);
}
```